# Extracting special rules in association analysis

Tags: r, apriori, arules

How can I extarct rules which in `lhs`only one special Item appear

```
1  {231050}                      => {231051} 0.06063479 1.0000000  16.492183
2  {231050,231051}               => {275001} 0.05490568 0.9055145   6.576661
3  {231050,275001}               => {231051} 0.05490568 1.0000000  16.492183
```

I would like to extract only first row in which I have only one `231050`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arules` has a `subset` function (see `?arules::subset`), which you can use to draw a subset of rules meeting your criteria - like specific items on lhs, minimum support etc:

```
library(arules)
data("Adult")
rules <- apriori(Adult, parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9, minlen = 2))
item <- "race=White"
rules.sub <- subset(rules, lhs %in% item & size(lhs)==1)
inspect(rules.sub)
#   lhs             rhs                            support   confidence lift     
# 7 {race=White} => {native-country=United-States} 0.7881127 0.9217231  1.0270761
# 8 {race=White} => {capital-gain=None}            0.7817862 0.9143240  0.9966616
# 9 {race=White} => {capital-loss=None}            0.8136849 0.9516307  0.9982720
```

Comment: Great solution. I would rewrite your subset as 
rules.sub <- subset(rules, lhs %in% item & size(lhs)==1) 
which explicitly states what item you want in the lhs and that the lhs of the rule can only include one item (i.e., size of lhs is 1). You can also rewrite it as a regular subset with '[' as:
 rules.sub <- rules[lhs(rules) %in% item & size(lhs(rules))==1]

Comment: That's it! I was looking for `size` and didn't find it in the doc. So let's make it `subset(rules, lhs %in% item & size(lhs)==1)`. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming the rules are generated using apriori):

```
df <- as(rules, 'data.frame')
df$rules <- as.character(df$rules)
lhs <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(df$rules, split='=>'))[,1]
lhs.items <- strsplit(lhs, split=',')
indices <- which(lapply(lhs.items, length) == 1)
special.item <- '231050'
special.indices <- which(grepl(special.item, lhs.items[[indices]]))
selected.rules <- df[special.indices,]
selected.rules

  rules     support  confidence          lift
1 {231050}=>{231051} 0.06063479          1 16.49218
```

Comment: in the second line I get the error: Error in strsplit(df$rules, split = "=>") : non-character argument

Comment: convert the rules column to to character, updated the code.

Comment: Error in lhs.items[[indices]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

Comment: can u print your lhs.items, it should be a list

Comment: it is a lis: List of 125
 $ : chr "{} "
 $ : chr "{} "
 $ : chr "{} "
 $ : chr "{} "
 $ : chr "{} "
 $ : chr "{275006} "
 $ : chr "{211050} "
 $ : chr "{275006} "
 $ : chr "{274001} "
 $ : chr "{231050} "
 $ : chr "{231051} "
 $ : chr "{231050} "

Comment: which is fine, what's there in indices?

Comment: can you make it work with the toy example you have given first? it must work.